# search in datatable using jquery not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a datatable fill in with the names and dates of birth, and two inputs (dates), I want to look for people who born between these two dates chosen, the search is done very well, but datatable displays the people separate, for example , in my example if I want people born between the date 2020-02-11 and the date 2020-02-22, in 1st page it does not display anything, and page 2 display `siad 2020-02-11`, month he wants fill in the 1st page after the 2nd.

**index.php**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class=" col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
         <div class="form-group col-md-3">
          <label for="titre">start date</label>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group col-md-5">
           <input type="date" name="datep" id="from" class="form-control">
         </div>
       </div>

     <div class=" col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
       <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label for="titre">end date</label>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group col-md-5">
         <input type="date" name="datep" id="to" class="form-control">
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>name</th>
          <th>date</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="b">
         <tr>
          <td>najib</td>
          <td>2020-02-01</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>jack</td>
          <td>2020-02-02</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>resou</td>
          <td>2020-02-03</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>ali</td>
          <td>2020-02-04</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>kamal</td>
          <td>2020-02-05</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>med</td>
          <td>2020-02-06</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>najat</td>
          <td>2020-02-07</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>fouad</td>
          <td>2020-02-08</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>hajar</td>
          <td>2020-02-09</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>redouane</td>
          <td>2020-02-10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>siad</td>
          <td>2020-02-11</td>
          <td>16</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
           <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>date birth</th>
           </tr>
      </tfoot>
</table>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js" integrity="sha256-4iQZ6BVL4qNKlQ27TExEhBN1HFPvAvAMbFavKKosSWQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();

    $("#from,#to").bind('keyup change', function() {
    var val1 = moment($('#from').val().toLowerCase(), 'YYYY/MM/DD');
    var val2 = moment($('#to').val().toLowerCase(), 'YYYY/MM/DD');
    $("#b").find('tr').filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle((moment($(this).find('td').text().toLowerCase(),
        'YYYY/MM/DD') >= (val1) || !val1["_isValid"]) && (moment($(this).find('td').text()
        .toLowerCase(),
        'YYYY/MM/DD') <= (val2) || !val2["_isValid"]))

    });
  })
} );
   </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are hiding/showing the rows in your code. You should delegate the drawing of the table to the datatable itself.

In order to allow filtering by range you can define a custom filtering function, as explained in the [docs](https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html).

In your particular case, this should work:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

var $from = $('#from');
var $to = $('#to');

// Define custom search function that will be executed every time the datable
// is redrawn.
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
    var min = moment($from.val().toLowerCase(), 'YYYY/MM/DD');
    var max = moment($to.val().toLowerCase(), 'YYYY/MM/DD');
    var date = moment(data[1].toLowerCase(), 'YYYY/MM/DD'); // use data of the date column. 

    if (!min.isValid() && !max.isValid()) {
        return true;
    }

    if ((!min.isValid() || date >= min) && (!max.isValid() || date <= max)) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
});

// Redraw table each time one of the input changes.
$("#from,#to").on('keyup change', function() {
    table.draw();
});
```